# Getting the content of paragraph in tinymce

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Is it possible to get the  content of a clicked paragraph in tinymce? If yes, how?

For ex: I have paragraph as shown below

I will use '|' to denote cursor

```
<p>123</p>
<p>45|6</p>
<p>789</p>
```

I should get output as

```
<p>456</p>
```

Any help would be appreciated.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode()
```

Take a look at this TinyMCE Fiddle for an example of how you might do this: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/xAfaab

Comment: Thank you. I just made a little change to the script to meet my needs. See link http://fiddle.tinymce.com/xAfaab/1